# Directx 11.0 with visual studio 2012 on windows 8 64 bit

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2012, directx-11

I want to begin learning DirectX 11.0 . I have Visual Studio 2012 ultimate installed on windows 8 pro 64 bit. I want to be able to develop games that would run in windows 7 as well.
Is this possible without downloading June 2010 SDK? or will the Windows SDK do? Can somebody post links to the right tutorials please?
I do not prefer 3rd party solutions and I want to avoid downloading the June 2010 SDK if possible.

Notes:
I have some experience with 3D game development in XNA.
I am a total newbie to DirectX.

Update:
DX SDK is now included in Windows SDK. 
But I have not seen any tutorial talking about developing desktop games using this already included SDK.
Most of them ask to download DX June 2010 SDK; probably these tutorials have not updated themselves after arrival of VS2012.
And the recent ones talk about porting a VS2010 DX game to VS2012, and the first step generally is to download the DX June 2010 SDK.

Therefore, I am beginning to suspect whether it is possible to build desktop games using this new inbuilt SDK?
Or indeed one has to download the June 2010 DX SDK?
or June SDK needs to be downloaded only when porting VS2010 games to VS2012?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to download the DX SDK from MSDN I read the documentation

> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh452744.aspx

Comment: Thank you for a speedy reply.
But the link you gave is about windows 8 store metro style games.I want to develop desktop games(using DX 11.0) that would run on windows 7 as well.

Comment: No problem but I really don't know where MSDN DX developer center on MSDN website they change MSDN

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's a kind of thing I was looking for. Wonder how I could not google that up. Any further help (more links) will be deeply appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Programs compiled on visual studio 2012 with the built in SDK should work perfectly well on windows 7 (subject of course to not using any new API calls or anything). I'm running vs2012 on windows 7 using d3d11 and the programs it builds run perfectly well on there.

Comment: Thanks for the really speedy response. Can You point me to any tutorials that show how to build desktop games with the new inbuilt SDK please... I am a newbie to DX